# Is intersectable a valid word?

Tags: etymology

I use the word intersectable quite a lot in my software documenation. I use it to describe an item, typically of some geometric shape, which can be the subject of tests for intersection (with other geometry). This is to distinguish such items from those which are not to be tested and thus not able to intersect (not intersectable).

There is probably another valid usage to describe geometry which cannot be intersected for some other (for example mathematical) reason.

Word 2010 doesn't recognise the word and an Internet search for the word only results in the definitions for intersect, with no mention of intersectable.

So, is intersectable a valid word?

Comment: Well your internet search hasn't shown anything, so no it's not a recognised word. Is it understandable to anyone reading your technical documentation? Yes. So does it matter if it's a word? Up to you / your manager.

Comment: But something which can be the subject of tests for intersection is not "intersectable"  if it fails the tests, is it?

Comment: @Clare Sure it is. It's intersectable, but it's not intersecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not in the English dictionary. However that being said the English language is an evolving language. There are many, many words in common use which are not in the dictionary.

Adding -able to words is a very common form of creating adjectives, also known as adjectivation. Anyone speaking English will immediately recognize the meaning of this word. I would say it's perfectly acceptable to use this form and it meets the rules for not using "ible" as it does not end in a soft "c" or "g" sound. However even those have been ignored in some of our English words. For example "change" ends in a soft g so it should be "changeible", but the word we use is "changeable".

I would say continue using it. It's a valid form of creating an adjective from a common word.

Furthermore it can be found in books as far back as 1821: 
[A link to the usage of the word "intersectable" in a published work](https://books.google.com/books?id=8YsaAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA16-PA4&lpg=RA16-PA4&dq=intersectable&source=bl&ots=SmAwe1azSg&sig=2arJ3xPUmMfKfgR0BLXu9w7f_3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib1IGhh_PUAhXsx4MKHXXJCv84FBDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=intersectable&f=false)